# parse_str - first argument in url does not get parsed

Tags: php

If you have something like that:

```
$string = 'http://test.com?quality=small&data=test';
parse_str($string);
var_dump($quality);
```

You will see the the first argument after the `?` does not get parsed.

How can i fix this?

Comment: You should put a `/` after the domain (`http://test.com/?qual...`).

Comment: Thanks but thats not a option.

Comment: Pass only string after "?" to parse_str().

Comment: The solution from kingkero works fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.parse-url.php) first and then `parse_str` on the returned `query`.

```
$parsed_url = parse_url($string);
parse_str($parsed_url['query']);
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But can you pls explain why? I don't get it. If i use parse_url alone it does still not work. Only with both. Why? Thanks

Comment: That doesn't answer his question

Comment: Yes it works, but it doesn't explain why the first variable after `?` is ignored

Comment: @scrowler Well the question was "how" ;) And honestly I don't know why

Comment: kingkero would be nice if you could answer my first comment.

Comment: @kingkero - fair enough, I'm interested in why - I can only presume `parse_str` is not built to handle complete URLs, but it's strange and should be in the docs

Comment: @Michael As I said I honestly don't know but I think like scrowler, that `parse_str` wasn't (originally) designed for complete URLs, as the docs e.g. show only the query parameters being passed to the function

Comment: Very strange thing. Maybe someone wants to report that to php. Looks like a bug honestly